# How to Copy Drupal 7 site with only Admin access No FTP

Tags: php, drupal, backup

I broke up with my boyfriend so he changed the FTP password to my Drupal 7 website he was hosting through his host.

I still have admin access but that's about it.

I can get the database(s).

But without FTP I can't get the files.

Ran this on a Drupal basic page

```
echo ini_get("disable_functions");
```

The following functions are disabled

exec,system,passthru,shell_exec,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,
proc_close,proc_open,dl,popen,show_source

Is there anything I can do!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got backup_migrate you could get the database. If you've got views you could build a view to list the files or anything else you need. This would be difficult but it could work.

Edit:

From memory, a user can browse their files with IMCE if that is installed. You could get it to browse the same directory that the file field uses.

Comment: I've got backup_migrate so I can get the DB.. just waiting til I can get the files to pull both at the same time.

Not familiar with Views.. How does that work?

Comment: You'd have to look up some tutorials on views as it's fairly complex. But you should be able to get views to list all the files you want. How many files are you talking about? Also, there's imce. It could show you your files. Also: get the database now. You can always get it again.

Answer (score 0):

Without shell access or ftp access no. You can try and contact the host and ask for a dump, but if it is under his name I doubt they would do anything for you. Or even just ask your boyfriend to be nice and see what comes of it (never know till you ask).

Other then that sounds like you are out of luck.

Comment: Gosh I hope you are wrong! Thanks for the reply though. I've been looking at PEAR Archive_Tar library. Is there anyway to tell if that is running on the host?